# CMake - OpenCV - cannot find -lDisplayImage

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to build a project on C++ with opencv using `Cmake`. But there is an error that I couldn't able to solve. I have searched a lot but found nothing.

**Note:**
I am beginner to OpenCV. So I don't even know why this library required. Just doing same insructions with a website.

Error is `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lDisplayImage`.

My `code`:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // read image
    Mat img = imread("foo.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);

    // show it in the window
    imshow("Window Name",img);

    waitKey();
}
```

My `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(image_processing)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(image_processing ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries( image_processing DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

My compile output:

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable image_processing
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lDisplayImage
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/image_processing.dir/build.make:137: recipe for target 'image_processing' failed
make[3]: *** [image_processing] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/image_processing.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/image_processing.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/image_processing.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/image_processing.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'image_processing' failed
make: *** [image_processing] Error 2
```

Output of `ld -ldisplayimage --verbose` command:

```
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdisplayimage.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdisplayimage.a failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdisplayimage.so failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdisplayimage.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdisplayimage.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdisplayimage.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libdisplayimage.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libdisplayimage.a failed
attempt to open //lib64/libdisplayimage.so failed
attempt to open //lib64/libdisplayimage.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib64/libdisplayimage.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib64/libdisplayimage.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libdisplayimage.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libdisplayimage.a failed
attempt to open //lib/libdisplayimage.so failed
attempt to open //lib/libdisplayimage.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libdisplayimage.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libdisplayimage.a failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libdisplayimage.so failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libdisplayimage.a failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libdisplayimage.so failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libdisplayimage.a failed
ld: cannot find -ldisplayimage
```

I tried to find that library but I couldn't able to find. I checked all of my `lib` folders.

My opencv installed on `/opt/opencv/` and built on `/opt/opencv/release/`.

Thanks for any help. I don't know anything about how to solve it.

Comment: What is the `DisplayImage` library you're unsuccesfully trying to to link with, and what does it have to do with OpenCV?

Comment: I have added my code.

Comment: You still haven't answered the above, and I still don't see any errors related to OpenCV. You're trying to link with some obscure library you haven't explained, which the linker cannot find, and which apparently isn't even used by your code.

Comment: I just doing same insructions of installing guide from a website. Without DisplayImage, compiler gives an error (I'm not on linux atm, can't write exact error). And I am beginner to openCV. So I don't know what is this library too.

Comment: Remove `DisplayImage` from `CMakeLists.txt`. Looks like it's just a leftover copy-n-paste artifact from following OpenCV [demo](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you copy and paste from examples without understanding them well. The problem is in the CMakeLists.txt

you have

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(image_processing)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(image_processing ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries( image_processing DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

I will go line by line here. First it checks that you have a minimum cmake version (to make sure some of the functions afterwards are valid), then is the name of the project obviously, it can be whatever you want. Then you find OpenCV library and this sets several variables (includes, libs, etc). Then you set c++11 standard and your source files, in this case it is just 1 for THIS executable (you can put as many as you need to, the same with .h if needed).

Finally the important part, add_executable which you pass 2 arguments, the name of the executable (it can be whatever) and the sourcefiles... you can even write the source file manually instead of setting them into a variable first. After that you say which libraries are going to be linked to your executable... here is where you have the error!! You have to put as first argument the same name of the executable you declare before, followed by the libraries used. When you did `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)` it set the libraries name in `$(OpenCV_LIBS)` variable. If you need another library you can put the name manually and it will link it while compiling it. In this case you have the name DisplayImage, and it thinks it is a library name and tries to link it, this means `-lDisplayImage` while compiling.

This means that you remove this and it should compile :)

```
target_link_libraries( image_processing  ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Also, after finding the OpenCV package I would recommend you to do

```
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
```

This will make sure the include folder is added to the compilation. Equivalent in gcc to the -Ifolder/path option. If you have to include more folders from different libraries project, you can use this command.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Oh.. Thanks for that great comment.

Comment: @Zaphiel I always think that giving the solution without explaining will lead to the same mistake in the future, but if you understand the problem it won't happen again :)